# BPLs of packages go to wrong package output directory

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe

I have a project group with several packages, some of them requiring others in the same project group. The packages do not all have the same package output directory set. And here is it where the problem starts. Depending on which package I build the BPLs go some time to one directory, another time to a different one.

I try to simplify what's going on. Say we have two packages `PackLib` and `PackDependent`. `PackDependent` has `PackLib` in its "Requires" list. `PackLib`'s "Package output directory" is "C:\PackLib", `PackDependent`'s directory is "C:\PackDependent". Here is the problem: When I build `PackLib` then the bpl goes to "C:\PackLib" - this is what I want. But when I build `PackDependent` then also `PackLib` is built (which is ok) but this time the PackLib.bpl goes to "C:\PackDependent" (expected: "C:\PackLib")!

In my context this causes all kinds of weird behavior, as the BPLs keep getting generated to different directories, depending on the package I build.

Am I missing something I need to configure? I want my packages to go always to the configured "Package output directory"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is probably happening is that your dependent package is being implicitly built as a result of the another package. When that happens, the outer-most package's compiler options are what get used for all packages being built. What you can do is switch to always building your packages explicitly by setting the{$IMPLICITBUILD OFF} directive in each package dpk file. As long as you explicitly build all the packages from the top of the dependency tree down, you should never encounter an error or have the packages put into the wrong location.

Comment: Hi Allen, being a colleague of Heinrich, I can confirm that your assumption is correct: The dependant package is beeing implicitly built. What surprises me, is that the compiler options from the outer-most package overrides the options of the depandant packages. Is there any deeper logic behind this, that I just don't know ?

Comment: The compiler is invoked with a specific set of options, namely the output path. When building the dependent package, it doesn't know from where to get any other options since the overall compilation process is still running. Implicit package compilation has other issues besides this, which is why I usually recommend explicit compilation for packages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately this collides with the often proposed solution for solving "[DCC Error] E2466 Never-build package 'A' requires always-build package 'B'" (where B is a third party package which has implicit building on and no source) which is to set {$IMPLICITBUILD ON} for A. And it's also a bit sad because I think the implicit building _could_ be a really useful feature.